# Converting Apache RewiteRule to Nginx's

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

i just installed nginx up and running for serving static content on my site. 
it works great but the apache rewrite rule about images (ofcourse) stoped working.

and i don't have an idea how to convert and in whcih file to put .

This is what i was using on apache :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?imgzzz.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule i/image_(\d+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif) pic/$1 [L]
```

Its purpose is to redirect directly accessed images to the image page instead.

Thanks in advance :) 
cheers

Comment: please move to serverfault.com for better chance get answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

k i found the answer myself on doing some research. leaving it here in case anyone else needs it

```
location /i/image_ {

location ~ ^/i/image_(?<IMAGE>\d+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {
valid_referers imgzzz.com www.imgzzz.com;

if ($invalid_referer) {
rewrite ^ /pic/$IMAGE;
}
}
}
```

Comment: pick your answer as solution, please